# Haskell: shared letters between two words

Tags: algorithm, haskell, duplicates

I just started learning Haskell. I am trying to get the list of all common letters between two words, for example, for `"hello"` and `"llama"` that would be `[ 'l', 'l' ]`, for `"happy"` and `"pay"`, `[ 'a', 'p', 'y' ]`.

I tried using intersect but I have trouble with duplicates, `"happy"` and `"pay"` result in `[ 'a', 'p', 'p', 'y' ]`. I can't just remove duplicates cause they can exist, as in the first example.

I would be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: How about you make a recursive function that walks down the first list and removes the matching element from the second list if/when encountered?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [multiset](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset) package:

```
Data.MultiSet> fromList "hello" `intersection` fromList "llama"
fromOccurList [('l',2)]
Data.MultiSet> fromList "happy" `intersection` fromList "pay"
fromOccurList [('a',1),('p',1),('y',1)]
```

The [data-ordlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) package also offers this functionality:

```
Data.List Data.List.Ordered> sort "hello" `isect` sort "llama"
"ll"
Data.List Data.List.Ordered> sort "happy" `isect` sort "pay"
"apy"
```

Comment: Since the OP is learning Haskell, I guess she want to code this herself as an exercise. In such case, I'd suggest to follow the last solution, exploiting `sort`, and re-write `isect` by plain recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an ideal case to use Data.Map. I would implement this as follows;

```
import qualified Data.Map.Lazy as M

sharedLetters :: String -> String -> String
sharedLetters s1 s2 = let cm = foldr (checkMap (\(x,y) -> (x,y+1))) charMap s2
                               where checkMap f c m = if M.member c m then M.adjust f c m
                                                                      else M.insert c (f (0,0)) m
                                     charMap        = foldr (checkMap (\(x,y) -> (x+1,y))) M.empty s1
                      in M.foldlWithKey (\r k (v1,v2) -> r ++ replicate (minimum [v1,v2]) k) "" cm

main :: IO String
main = do
  putStr "Enter first string  :"
  s1 <- getLine
  putStr "Enter second string :"
  s2 <- getLine
  return $ sharedLetters s1 s2

Enter first string  :happy
Enter second string :pay
"apy"

Enter first string  :pay
Enter second string :happy
"apy"

Enter first string  :hello
Enter second string :llama
"ll"

Enter first string  :llama
Enter second string :hello
"ll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice technique that's worth learning.  Suppose you have two sorted lists:

```
[1,1,5,10,15,15,18]
[2,5,8,10,15,20]
```

and you want to merge them together into a single sorted list.  In Haskell, there's a very elegant way to write this algorithm using pattern matching and guards:

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     =  x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | otherwise =  y : merge (x:xs) ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
```

so that:

```
> merge [1,1,5,10,15,15,18] [2,5,8,10,15,20]
[1,1,2,5,5,8,10,10,15,15,15,18,20]
>
```

In a nutshell, when both lists are non-empty, it compares the heads of both lists and outputs the smallest head; then it uses recursion to output "the rest".

It could also have been written with the three cases (less, greater, and equal) all made explicit:

```
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     =  x : merge xs (y:ys)
                    | x > y     =  y : merge (x:xs) ys
                    | otherwise =  y : merge (x:xs) ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
```

and this general template can be used to implement a number of interesting algorithms on sorted lists.  Here's one that removes common elements, for example:

```
uncommon (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     =  x : uncommon xs (y:ys)
                       | x > y     =  y : uncommon (x:xs) ys
                       | otherwise =  uncommon xs ys
uncommon xs [] = xs
uncommon [] ys = ys
```

so that:

```
> uncommon [1,1,5,10,15,15,18] [2,5,8,10,15,20]
[1,1,2,8,15,18,20]
>
```

You might want to try modifying the `uncommon` function to create a `diff` function that outputs the result of removing the elements of the second list from the first.  It will require modifying one of the first three guarded cases, and you'll also need to adjust one of the two "empty list" pattern matches:

```
> diff [1,1,5,10,15,15,18] [2,5,8,10,15,20]
[1,1,15,18]
>
```

Once you've figured this out, you'll find it easy to create a `common` function that outputs the shared elements of the two sorted lists to give:

```
> common [1,1,5,10,15,15,18] [2,5,8,10,15,20]
[5,10,15]
>
```

Since strings are just lists of characters, this would work for your problem, too, using `sort` from `Data.List` to pre-sort the lists:

```
> import Data.List
> common (sort "hello") (sort "llama")
"ll"
> common (sort "happy") (sort "pay")
"apy"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about exploiting the fact that every letter shared between the words (allowing duplicates) shows up as a pair of that letter in the set formed from the union of those words?  You can find such pairs efficiently by sorting the union set and picking out duplicates -

```
let find_dups ([]) = []; find_dups (x:y:xs) | x == y = x:find_dups(xs); find_dups (x:xs) = find_dups(xs)                                              
let common_letters word1 word2 = find_dups (sort (word1 ++ word2))

> common_letters "hello" "fellows"
"ello"
```